# Is it possible to check for an alert with selenium webdriver without an implicit wait?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Everything I've been able to find seems to indicate that you must do some form of WebDriverWait when checking for popup alerts with selenium webdriver, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python). It seems like most people are trying to verify an expected alert happens, but I am trying to catch if any unexpected alert happens after any action.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995769/2149641) seems to indicate that this may be an enhancement to throw an exception on alerts, has this been implemented yet? Or, is implicitly waiting for an alert the best current solution? If wanting to check that any action results in an alert, that is a lot of wasted time waiting.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [DesiredCapabilites](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities), at least the firefox driver has the unexpectedAlertBehaviour.

From the docs:

> What the browser should do with an unhandled alert before throwing out
>   the UnhandledAlertException. Possible values are "accept", "dismiss"
>   and "ignore"

The DesiredCapabilities must be passed to the driver in constuctor. Check [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear in terms of what you want to *do* with the Alert if/when you get one.

The title says you want to check if an alert is present, which implies that by nature it is not `Unexpected`. If you know when an alert is happening and expect it to happen after a certain action, then an Implicit wait would be the way to go.

In the question you say 'I am trying to catch if any unexpected alert happens', which implies a you don't really know when an alert will be given, or it's not consistent. This path could have two outcomes:

- If the alert causes a problem with continuing your test then I think you have a problem with your test case design (and/or the application), and you should work out why the alert is happening, make sure it's reproducible, and then either. Try/catch blocks and debug mode will be your friend here, but shouldn't end up in your finished test code.
- If you don't care about the alert, and if you can continue with your test after either accepting or rejecting it, then DesiredCapabilities as Erki points out, should do what you want. Beware though that this will accept/reject/ignore ALL unhandled alert exceptions throughout the running of your test, potentially causing unexpected behaviour.

Some people differ, but IMO, you should always know when Alerts are going to happen (or not), and be using implicit waits to handle them. If you're tests are failing because of `UnhandledAlertException`'s then you either have a problem with your tests, or a problem with your application under test, and in my experience, usually it's with the tests.

Trying to complete actions before Ajax calls are complete is especially prone to throwing UnhandledAlertExceptions (again, in my experience). I have this little helper method that solved a lot of my problems (C# code)

```
    public void WaitForAjax()
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
    }
```

Comment: With this particular application, there is a lot of user configuration; providing input, clicking submit, kind of thing. I am not expecting an alert on submit, but sometimes it will happen either because the input was incorrect in some way, or because there was a problem committing the action (usually a bug). If I want to catch any alerts that *may* occur, I wonder if just wrapping the "submits" with a try and except for UnexpectedAlertPresentException makes the most sense. For what I want to do with the alert, I want to throw an exception and print the alert text (the try/except would work).